# How to check who is logged in on jail?

Tags: freebsd, bsd

Is there an easy way to check who is logged in on any [jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail)?

Answer (score 1):

How about running following from the host system?

```
jexec <jid> w
```

Like:

```
# jexec 19 w
11:38AM  up 8 days,  3:17, 1 user, load averages: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER             TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
root             p2       127.0.0.2        11:30AM     8 -csh (csh)
```

Comment: Thx for a tip. I this that way:

jls | awk '\!/JID/ { print $1 }' | xargs -I % jexec % who